# WCF Rest coed for Json

Tags: c#, json, wcf, rest, interface

Usually I see the code of WCF REST JSON is likely:

```
// Start the service and browse to <a href="http://:/SampleService/help[ServiceContract]  public">http://<machine_name>:<port>/SampleService/help [ServiceContract]
 public interface ISampleService {
[WebGet(UriTemplate = "")]
List<SampleItem> GetCollection();
```

That means interface is introduced. But in some occurence I saw in the code interface is never used at all.
Such as

```
 [ServiceContract(Namespace = "")]
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
public class AlertService
{
    AlertContext alertProxy = new AlertContext();
    AlertDetailsContext alertDetailProxy = new AlertDetailsContext();
    Analytics analyticsProxy = new Analytics();

    [OperationContract]
    [WebInvoke(BodyStyle=WebMessageBodyStyle.Bare, RequestFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, ResponseFormat=WebMessageFormat.Json, UriTemplate="/SearchAlerts")]
    public List<Alert> SearchAlerts(AlertFilter filter)
    {
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Cache-Control", "no-cache, must-revalidate");
        WebOperationContext.Current.OutgoingResponse.Headers.Add("Expires", "Sat, 26 Jul 1997 05:00:00 GMT");
```

Here class is used directly, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the `ServiceContract` doesn't have to be an `interface` contract. Using an interface allows you to share the same contract among multiple implementations and can make unit testing possible, but it is not required.